# Stubbing an api request from a form on my site when testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec, capybara

I have a page on a website I'm creating and it submits data via a form to the stripe API and I wanted to know if it's possible to stub this out in capybara tests as this slows down my test suite when I have it making the actual request, are there any solutions to this?

Here's my code:-

Order model-only the create_payment method I use for the call

Model:-

```
 def self.create_payment_method(payment)
   c = Stripe::Customer.create({ :card => { :number => payment[:number], :exp_month => payment[:month], 
  :cvc => payment[:cvc], :exp_year => payment[:year] }})

  stripe_response = c["cards"]["data"][0]

  payment_attr = self.new
  payment_attr.assign_attributes({:last_four => stripe_response["last4"], :card_type =>   stripe_response["type"], 
  :expiry_year => stripe_response["exp_year"], :expiry_month => stripe_response["exp_month"], :stripe => c.id, 
  :month => payment[:month], :year => payment[:year], :user_id => payment[:user_id] })
  payment_attr.save!
 rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  logger.error "Stripe error while trying to create the payment method: #{e.message}"
  errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit/debit card."
  false
end
```

View:-

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">
   <%= label_tag(:card_no, "Card Number") %>
  </label>
  <div class="controls">
   <%= f.text_field :number %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">
   <%= label_tag(:CVC) %>
  </label>
 <div class="controls">
   <%= f.text_field :cvc %>
</div>
```

```
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label">
   <%= label_tag(:expiry_month) %>  
 </label>
 <div class="controls">
   <%= f.text_field(:month) %>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label">
  <%= label_tag(:expiry_year) %>  
 </label>
<div class="controls">
 <%= f.text_field(:year) %>
</div>

<%= f.hidden_field(:user_id, :value => current_user.id) %>
<%= f.submit(:class => "btn") %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) gem was created to handle cases just like this. It will let you record a real response from a remote API but stub those calls in future runs of the test suite so that your tests do not depend on and cannot modify data in the external API.

One of my coworkers wrote up a nice summary of his approach in [how to test external apis](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/18/how-to-test-external-apis/) if that's helpful.